# Does citrus framework runs on Java 1.6

Tags: citrus-framework

Does citrus framework runs on Java 1.6? the 1.X version isn't mentioned in the documentation.

As per latest docs

> Java 7 or higher
>
> Installed JDK plus JAVA_HOME environment variable set up and pointing
>   to your Java installation directory
>
> Java IDE
>
> A Java IDE will help you manage your Citrus project, create and
>   execute test cases. Just use the Java IDE that you are used to (e.g.
>   Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA).
>
> Maven 3.0.x or higher Citrus tests will be executed with the Apache
>   Maven build tool. You can also run tests via ANT but Maven is my
>   preferred way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope per the documentation:

http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/#setup-using-ant

> Before we start with the Citrus setup be sure to meet the following preconditions. The following software should be installed on your computer, in order to use the Citrus framework:
>
> ***Java 7 or higher***
>
> Installed JDK plus JAVA_HOME environment variable set up and pointing to your Java installation directory

Java 7 is version 1.7 so 1.6 would not be expected to run correctly